# Retrieve timeoffset using Jakcson to parse json datetime

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, jackson, dropwizard

I am using Dropwizard to implement some REST webservices.

User will send date-time using iso format, like:
`"beginTime": "2016-03-30T16:56:35.43-10:00"`

I need to get the local date and hour sent by the user or the offset.

Jackson seems to loose the offset information and set date to UTC.
Into my object deserialized from json I get `2016-03-31T02:56:35.430Z` I have tried all type (`Calendar`, `DateTime`, `Date`).

I need to know the offset or the *user* day to compute daily stats on the user's timezone.

I have tried `DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE` with no success.

How can I get the offset or/and the input date?

Comment: I have found a way using `DateTime.parse` and with a specific `JsonDeserializer` but it's look overkill to use a specific Deserializer for a so basic stuf.

Comment: Hi @Ôrel di you take a look at my answer?

Answer (score 0):

For java8 you can deserialize a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) instance by using the library [jackson-datatype-jsr310](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.7.3). You have to register a [`JavaTimeModule`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/JavaTimeModule.java) and disable the deserialization feature `ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE` :

```
String json = "\"2016-03-30T16:56:35.430-10:00\"";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule=new JavaTimeModule();
mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE);
mapper.registerModule(javaTimeModule);
ZonedDateTime obj = mapper.readValue(json, ZonedDateTime.class);
System.out.println(obj);
//prints: 2016-03-30T16:56:35.430-10:00
```

Or you can deserialize a [`org.joda.time.DateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) instance by adding the library [jackson-datatype-joda](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-joda/2.7.3) and registering a [`JodaModule`](http://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-joda/2.6.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/joda/JodaModule.html).

```
String json = "\"2016-03-30T16:56:35.430-10:00\"";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JodaModule jodaModule=new JodaModule();
mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE);
mapper.registerModule(jodaModule);
DateTime obj = mapper.readValue(json, DateTime.class);
System.out.println(obj);
//prints: 2016-03-30T16:56:35.430-10:00
```